# Displaying Menu Items on Different Pages

Tags: css, menu

I have 2 sets of menu items in my navigation bar.

Set 1 is labelled ".homemenuitem"

Set 2 is labelled ".othermenuitem"

I want  to display homemenuitems on the home page and othermenuitems on every other page.

I was hoping to do this with CSS.

I started with the following

```
.home .othermenuitem {
  display: none;
}
```

Which shows the correct menu on the home page, but I can't figure out how to hide the homemenuitems on every other page without using the unique page id (which will be a pain as the site grows).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have different pages then why are you including homemenuitems on those pages?

Answer (score 0):

This is where the 'Cascading' part of 'Cascading Style Sheets' is your friend. More specific rules always override less specific ones, so if you do this:

```
.homemenuitems {
    display: none;
}
.home .homemenuitems {
    display: block; /* or 'inline' or 'inline-block', as necessary */
}
```

then the latter rule will override the former where it matches (on the home page), and otherwise, the first rule will always take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you take the other way, making:

```
.homemenuitem {
  display: none;
}
```

In every single page of your web, and only showing it on the home page id?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael, tweaked it a bit further and this is what worked for me, if anybody is looking for a similar situation.

```
.homemenuitem {
    display: none;
}
.home .othermenuitem {
    display: none;
}
.home .homemenuitem {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried it on so many occasion , you can use this code .homemenuitem {     display: none; } .home .othermenuitem {     display: none; } .home .homemenuitem {     display: inline-block; }